# Install new font in Cpanel

Tags: html, css, fonts, cpanel, host

I made a website that have Persian font
Cpanel just have English font as defult
And it shows Persian texts like this
[This photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrEFb.png)

And [this](https://ariasabery.b6b.ir) is my Website

In my computer I opened Html files and fonts were completly.
I used this files in another Host and I had this problem.
How can I fix this problem in Cpanel?

Comment: That would not be in cPanel, but in your HTML or CSS code. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new fonts to your website using @font-face. You need to place the source font files in the root directory of your website then call them in your CSS stylesheet. Below is an example for [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Were is root dir ? I just have htdocs dir

Comment: add me on ggle chat i'll help you a bit laurentchevrette ''at'' gmail ''dot'' com